# Rollback: "Windows Server 2012 and TCP slow start"

Tags: iis-8

Can anyone tell me how to rollback on these settings?

https://www.iispeed.com/blog/windows-server-2012-and-tcp-slow-start

Answer (score 0):

Found this (also updated in the like above):

```
Remove-NetTransportFilter –SettingName InternetCustom
```